# "nvm use stable" sets node version to older than version installed by "nvm install stable"

Tags: node.js, nvm

Running `nvm install stable` installs and sets node to `v16.4.2`.
While running `nvm use stable` sets node to `v9.11.2`.

I guess I could run `nvm alias stable 16` but it feels like it takes away the point of having a generic word for the latest stable version

Printout from `nvm ls`:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [nvm documentation](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm):

> stable: this alias is deprecated, and only truly applies to node v0.12 and earlier. Currently, this is an alias for node.

and:

> Node has a schedule for long-term support (LTS) You can reference LTS versions in aliases and .nvmrc files with the notation lts/* for the latest LTS